# Java Spring App Entity (MySQL) timestamp is different at time of POST compared to value when using GET

Tags: java, mysql, spring, entity-framework

I wrote a set of CRUD functions for an entity called Item. The table for this entity has a field "date_created TIMESTAMP" with a corresponding variable

```
@CreatedDate
@JsonProperty("date_created")
private volatile Date dateCreated;
```

In the POST method, I create an Item object and do this

```
item = this.itemRepository.saveAndFlush(item);
// Do a bunch of stuff...
item.setName("Test Name");
return new ResponseEntity<Item>(item, HttpStatus.CREATED);
```

When I check date_created on the response of the POST call its value (ie. "1440499230691") is different than what's in the DB and the response of the GET method (ie. "1440499231000" ie. "2015-08-25 06:40:31").

Does anyone have any idea what the reason for this might be? I've been stuck on this issue for a while now without any leads. Anything would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check if the miliseconds are stored in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html

Comment: Thanks for the help. I added more precision ie. TIMESTAMP(6) and that seemed to have helped, but I don't understand why since I thought item = saveAndFlush() would have returned actual DB value. I even tried re-querying for the same item and returning that. 

I still have another problem that I think is related. In that method, I also have another entity called Collection and I set collection.date_modified = item.date_created. But I check the DB and collection.date_modified is a different value than item.date_created. Why would that happen?